# How to remove tags that have no content

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am working on some old html that features a lot of empty tags: `<i  style='mso-bidi-font-style:normal'><span style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:  Univers;mso-bidi-font-family:Arial'><o:p></o:p></span></i>`. This seriously destroys the algorithms I use to traverse the tree.

Is there a way to clean the BeautifulSoup object prior to traversing it?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_object = """
<i style='mso-bidi-font-style:normal'><span style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:
Univers;mso-bidi-font-family:Arial'><o:p></o:p></span></i>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_object, "lxml")
```

Not even `.prettify()` is able to remove empty tags:

```
>>> print(soup.prettify())
<html>
 <body>
  <i style="mso-bidi-font-style:normal">
   <span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:
  Univers;mso-bidi-font-family:Arial">
    <o:p>
    </o:p>
   </span>
  </i>
 </body>
</html>
```

I would like to see the output of this call completely empty.

Comment: They're not really empty if they contain a child, even if that child has nothing but another child.

Comment: Makes sense, but in this case `<o:p></o:p>` should count as empty, shoudn't it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If your focus is keeping just textual elements, how about the following approach? This removes all elements which contain no text, for example images. Add any tags such as `br` or `img` that must not be removed.

It really depends on what structure you want to remain.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_object = """
<i style='mso-bidi-font-style:normal'><span style='font-size:11.0pt;font-family:
Univers;mso-bidi-font-family:Arial'><o:p></o:p></span></i>
<i>hello world</i>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_object, "lxml")

for x in soup.find_all():
    if len(x.get_text(strip=True)) == 0 and x.name not in ['br', 'img']:
        x.extract()

print(soup)
```

Giving:

```
<html><body>
<i>hello world</i>
</body></html>
```

Comment: This will remove tags with images or other non-textual contents: `<div><img...></div>`

Comment: If you want to "whitelist" certain elements that you are fine with being "empty" you can do `if (len(x.get_text(strip=True)) == 0) and (x.name not in empty_whitelist):` where `empty_whitelist` is a list of tags that shouldn't be removed, like `['img', 'br']` etc.

Comment: @pzkpfw empty all tags excepts if the tag contains id.
ex:
 `<span id="this_is_anchor"><span>
<span></span>`

output:
`<span id="this_is_anchor"><span>`

Answer (score 16):

The existing answers in here have a slight problem as they all remove the `<br>` element which is always empty but crucial for the structure of the HTML.

**Keep all breaks**

```
 [x.decompose() for x in soup.findAll(lambda tag: not tag.contents and not tag.name == 'br' )]
```

Source

```
<p><p></p><strong>some<br>text<br>here</strong></p>
```

Output

```
<p><strong>some<br>text<br>here</strong></p>
```

---

**Remove also elements full of whitespace**

Also in case you also want to remove tags that only contain white-space you may want to do something like

```
[x.decompose() for x in soup.findAll(lambda tag: (not tag.contents or len(tag.get_text(strip=True)) <= 0) and not tag.name == 'br' )]
```

Source

```
<p><p>    </p><p></p><strong>some<br>text<br>here</strong></p>
```

Output

```
<p><strong>some<br>text<br>here</strong></p>
```

Comment: Also consider removing other fundamental but typically empty tags (often found in the head), e.g. <script>, <link>, meta etc.

Comment: Note `len(X) <= 0` is equivalent to `not X` here.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a way to remove any tag which has no content:

```
>>> html = soup.findAll(lambda tag: tag.string is None)
>>> [tag.extract() for tag in html]
>>> print(soup.prettify())
```

And output is an empty string for your example, since there's no tag has a content.

---

If you only want to remove tag which has no content, but don't remove tag which has attributes. Like only remove `<o:p></o:p>`, there's another way:

```
>>> html = soup.findAll(lambda tag: not tag.contents)
>>> [tag.extract() for tag in html]
>>> print(soup.prettify())
```

Output:

```
<i style="mso-bidi-font-style:normal">
 <span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:
Univers;mso-bidi-font-family:Arial">
 </span>
</i>
```

The `span` and `i` tags are saved because they have attributes, although there's no content.

Comment: What’s the difference between _empty_ and _really empty_?

Comment: @bfontaine After seeing this comment, I just give up to explain what I was trying to say 6 years ago... Then I look at my code, and edit the content instead.